# On the full list of near-repdigit perfect powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm interested in the full list of perfect powers ($a^b$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a \ge 1$, $b \ge 2$) that are *near-repdigit* in base 10. A near-repdigit is a $k$-digit number where $k \ge 2$ and precisely $k-1$ of the digits are equal.

[1] fully solves the case where $b=2$. [2] shows that <s>there are finitely many solutions when $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{b \ge 3}$</s> there are finitely many solutions for any *fixed* $b \ge 3$, excluding trivial solutions of the form $10^{bn}$ and $8 \times 1000^n$ (when $b = 3$), but it does not provide a full list.

A simple computer program suggests that there are no non-square nontrivial solutions other than 27, 32, 343, and 7776, but running the program for any amount of time would never prove that the list ends there. Is there any further development in the literature that presents the solutions? Or do any of you see how to prove that no other nontrivial solutions exist?

[1] A. Gica and L. Panaitopol, [On Oblath’s problem](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Panaitopol/panaitopol41.html)

[2] O. Kihel and F. Luca, [Perfect Powers With All Equal Digits But One](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251282896_Perfect_Powers_With_All_Equal_Digits_But_One)

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't [2] only show that for any particular $b$ there are only finitely many solutions?

Comment: Up to how many digits did you check?

Comment: @CommandMaster Oh, I guess I read wrong. So it doesn't exclude the possibility that there are infinitely many nontrivial solutions across all $b$s. I checked up to 24 digits and no others came up.